# Make a div which overlays an autoresizable image and is as high as the image but narrower and centered

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Web page with an image that autoresizes so it is always as wide as the page. Over this image, I want to superimpose four adjacent translucent panels with completely opaque text superimposed on them. The panels and text areas must be as high as the image. But the region occupied by the panels must be narrower than the image, centered within it with a specified maximum and minimum width. The effect should be like that in the screenshot below and in the live demo at http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test23.html , but with the panel region's left and right edges exactly aligned with those of the red bars:
[image: ........]

I made the demo work by using jQuery as explained below, but can what I want be done in pure CSS, without JavaScript? I'm asking because my jQuery code doesn't seem to get the alignment quite right. Also, although it is working on Firefox, it isn't on Chrome. On Chrome, the panel region is aligned with the left of the page.

To make my demo, I had the following hierarchy of divs and other elements. This can be seen in test23.html , with the IDs and classes defined as in the (commented) test23.css which it links to:

```
image-holder-div
  (This holds the image and overlays. I've made it relative
   so as start a new stacking context.)
  The image
  image-overlay-div
    (This must be as high as the image, but narrower
     and centered within it, with maximum and minimum
     width. Its left and right edges should be aligned
     with the red bars, i.e. with those of class 
     inner-div . I have given it height 100% and position
     absolute, so that it is as high as image-holder-div
     and defines its position relative to that. I set its
     'left' and 'width' by copying them from inner-div
     in jQuery.)
  image-overlay-segment-1-holder
    (This holds the first panel. It has height 100%,
     position absolute, z-index 10, and width and left 
     edge set so as to occupy the first quarter of 
     image-overlay-div.)
    image-pale-orange-overlay
      (This must go in front of the image. It has 
       an opacity of 0.2, width and height of 100%, 
       position absolute, and z-index 20.)
    image-text-overlay
      (This must go in front of the pale orange, 
       and the text must be completely opaque. It
       has height and width of 100%, position
       absolute, and z-index 30.)
  image-overlay-segment-2-holder, and similarly for panel 3 and 4
    (These work in the same way as above.)
```

The jQuery code that aligns image-overlay-div is:

```
function setPos()
{
  var its_left = $( ".inner-div" ).position().left;
  var its_width = $( ".inner-div" ).width();
  $( "#image-overlay-div" ).css( "left", its_left + "px" );
  $( "#image-overlay-div" ).css( "width", its_width + "px" );
}

$( document ).ready( setPos );

$( window ).resize( setPos );
```

The hierarchy above is the simplest I could devise that worked. One constraint I discovered is that I couldn't make the text overlay a child of the pale orange overlay, because then it inherits the latter's opacity, so that the text is translucent.

Also, in pure CSS, I couldn't work out a way to make image-overlay-div as high as the image but horizontally aligned as I wanted it. To make it as high as the image, I need it to have position absolute (I think), but then I can't see how to align it. If I change the position values so that I can align it, I then can't get the height right. That's why I resorted to JavaScript. But do I really need to, or am I missing some useful fact about CSS?

For anyone who wants to experiment with this without downloading the example from my site, I've included a [Stack Overflow code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) below.

```js
function setPos()
{ 
  var its_left = $( ".inner-div" ).position().left;
  var its_width = $( ".inner-div" ).width();
  $( "#image-overlay-div" ).css( "left", its_left + "px" );
  $( "#image-overlay-div" ).css( "width", its_width + "px" );
}

$( document ).ready( setPos );

$( window ).resize( setPos );
```

```css
.inner-div
  { width: 75%; 
    max-width: 700px; 
    min-width: 300px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
  }
/*
This styles the red lines across the top and
bottom of the page. In the site I'm building, 
most content has to sit between the left and
right edges this line defines. That includes
the image and its overlays. 
*/


#image-holder-div
  { position: relative;
  }
/*
A div holding the image and the divs that are 
overlaid onto it. I made the position is relative 
in order to create a new stacking content.
*/


.image 
  { height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
/*
Makes my image occupy 100% of the page width,
resizing as the browser does.
*/


#image-overlay-div
  { left: 99px;
    width: 99px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
/*
This div has the same size and
position as the image. I had to use
jQuery for this, to set the 'left'
and 'width' properties to those of
.inner-div . So the 99px's above
should get overwritten as soon as
the page loads.
*/


#image-overlay-segment-1-holder
  { left: 0.5%;
    top: 0;  
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
  }
/*
Holds the first pale overlay.
Note that width and position are
relative to image-overlay-div (not to the
entire page width), which should be 
the same as being relative to
.inner-div .
*/


#image-overlay-segment-2-holder
  { left: 25.5%;
    top: 0;  
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
  }
/*
Holds the 2nd pale overlay.
*/


#image-overlay-segment-3-holder
  { left: 50.5%;
    top: 0;  
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
  }
/*
Holds the 3rd pale overlay.
*/


#image-overlay-segment-4-holder
  { left: 75.5%;
    top: 0;  
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
  }
/*
Holds the 4th pale overlay.
*/


.image-pale-orange-overlay
  { background-color: orange;
    opacity: 0.2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
  }
/*
The class for the pale orange overlays.
These are translucent, so that the image
shows through them.
*/


.image-text-overlay
  { width: 100%; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 30;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }
/*
The class for text overlaying the pale
orange ovelay. This must be completely
opaque, so must not inherit the opacity
of the layer behind.
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class=inner-div style="margin-bottom:30px;">
</div>

<div id=image-holder-div>

  <img src="http://www.j-paine.org/catalogue/archers_big.jpeg" 
class=image>

  <div id=image-overlay-div>

    <div id=image-overlay-segment-1-holder>

      <div class=image-pale-orange-overlay>
      </div>

      <div class=image-text-overlay>
        <div><a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">READ</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End image-overlay-segment-1-holder -->

    <div id=image-overlay-segment-2-holder>

      <div class=image-pale-orange-overlay>
      </div>

      <div class=image-text-overlay>
        <div><a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">MORE</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End image-overlay-segment-2-holder -->

    <div id=image-overlay-segment-3-holder>

      <div class=image-pale-orange-overlay>
      </div>

      <div class=image-text-overlay>
        <div><a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">CARTOONS</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End image-overlay-segment-3-holder -->

    <div id=image-overlay-segment-4-holder>

      <div class=image-pale-orange-overlay>
      </div>

      <div class=image-text-overlay>
        <div><a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">HERE!</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End image-overlay-segment-4-holder -->

  </div>
  <!-- End image-overlay-div -->

</div>
<!-- End image-holder-div -->

<div class=inner-div style="margin-top:30px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A linked demo that we can't amend easily is of little value. A jsfiddle.net demo would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought if anyone did want to experiment, they'd prefer downloading the example and using their own editor. But I've appended a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Might something like this be what you are looking for?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8w972nw/

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgBg">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="rect">a</div>        
        <div class="rect">b</div>
        <div class="rect">c</div>
        <div class="rect">d</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgBg
{
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    background:url('http://placehold.it/1000x1000');
}

.wrap
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;

}

.rect
{
    text-align:center;
    height:500px;
    width:50px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:rgba(100, 50, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Jesse, thanks. Your answer was useful in showing me how to use flex, and that I can  collapse the text and translucent-background
panels into one if I use rgba, and that I can use a background image. I wasn't able to use your answer directly, because your image doesn't resize. I had to experiment a bit to make my background image resize in the best fashion. I tried http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test24.html and http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test25.html and http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test26.html . The Stackoverflow comment space is too meagre to explain these, but the demos do.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! You could easily make the .imgBg div responsive by changing it to width:100vw and height:100vh. (or any other number, since its just a % of the viewable window)

Comment: Should have thought of that. In coding my own version of 
Ryan Andrew Chudd's answer, I borrowed Gust van de Wal's trick of calculating image size using 'calc' and vw.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css approach.

```
#image-overlay-div
{ 
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;   
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -37.5%;
    position: absolute;
}
@media (min-width:933px){
    #image-overlay-div
    { 
    max-width: 700px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:400px){
    #image-overlay-div
    { 
    min-width: 300px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lauwrentius, thanks! I've not tried this yet, but it's useful. It replaces one messy rule by three that set the width in a more straightforward fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43x2L99e/) that I think does exactly what needs to happen. There is quite a few complex things in there, so I'll explain what I did.

I added the image as **background-image** to the body. I then created a container that holds the four items. To calculate its height, I made a `calc()` that calculates `100vw` (100% of the body's width), and divides it by 700 / 578 (the width and height of the image).

I then made the container a `flex` container, so it will keep the children in the center, with an equal amount of whitespace between them with `justify-content: space-between;`. Then to stretch them to 100% of the container's height, I applied `align-items: stretch;`.

And voila. It's done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gust, thanks. Your Fiddle works nicely. Your answer was useful for the same reasons as Jesse's; and also showed me align-items:stretch and that I could use 'calc'. You may have seen that I did so in making my own version of Ryan Andrew Chudd's answer. I'm not sure whether flex would give me quite enough control over horizontal spacing to satisfy the graphic designer I'm working with. But we may have to accept that: at least it's clean and it uses CSS in a straightforward way. I do need to see how compatible it is with today's mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I made the panels `display: inline-block;` and changed the way you do opacity by using `rgba`.

Here it is in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chuddayo/pen/PPOqyR)

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.j-paine.org/catalogue/archers_big.jpeg">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="panel-holder">
    <div id="panel-1" class="panel">SOME</div>
    <div id="panel-2" class="panel">CART</div>
    <div id="panel-3" class="panel">OONS</div>
    <div id="panel-4" class="panel">HURR</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
}
#panel-holder{
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 700px; 
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 2em auto 0;
}
.panel{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: black;
  margin: 0 .125%;
  height: 100vw;
}
```

I'll be honest I had difficulty getting the columns to expand vertically with no content in them. You may find you can remove `height: 100vw;` if your panels are full of content, or some other means of expanding them evenly. It breaks on small viewport sizes by having the fourth panel go underneath, which may be due to constrains on the `panel-holder`'s width.

Comment: Ryan, thanks! In yours, the panels went too far down, so I borrowed Gust van de Wal's trick of calculating their height using 'calc'. I also moved the image inside a div, to match my original demo. The result is at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbvZJe and http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test32.html . It's not quite right: the demo image I've used this time shows this. It's cropped, so I should see the panels go down no further than the bottom black ripple under the "MAKE $$$ FAST!" bottle. But they do, a bit. I can't see why. What I like about your answer is seeing how not to need z-indices.

Comment: I tried something to stop the panels going down a bit further than the image. I thought that if I used 'calc' to calculate both the image height and the panel height, the sizes would have to match. This seems to work. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpyLya and http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test33.html .

Comment: I've been trying to understand the stacking order in your demo. For reference, consider the rules in Steven Bradley's "Z-Index And The CSS Stack: Which Element Displays First?", http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/ . The body should be at the back, by rule 1. Then #wrapper above it, by rule 2 ("Block boxes in the normal flow, in order of appearance"). Then the image and then #panel-holder, by rule 3 ("positioned elements, in order of appearance"). Am I right? But why are the panels on top of these? Because of  rule 5 ("inline elements")? Is this why you made .panel inline-block?

Comment: I found a problem with the demo mentioned in the last comment but one, http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test33.html . If there's a lot of text in the panels, their tops don't all start in the same place. That's demonstrated in http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test34.html . I fixed that by adding  vertical-align:top to the panel class: see http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test35.html . I got the idea from http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/ , "What’s the Deal With Display: Inline-Block?" by Joshua Johnson.

Comment: Ryan, you said it breaks on small viewports. I found something similar when I checked my margins and widths. If I make each panel 25% wide, they don't fit. The fourth goes underneath. This seems to be because of what Chris Coyier explains in https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ . This space is like the space browsers put between words that you separate with space. Chris gives tricks to remove it. I used his trick of comments between the panel divs, so that the browser doesn't see any spaces there. See http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test36.html .

Answer (score 0):

Having experimented with the answers above, here's my answer to my question. It's in http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test37.html , and copied to the code snippet at the end.

Unlike the demo in my question, it uses no JavaScript. It derives mainly from Ryan Andrew Chudd's answer, augmented with Gust van de Wal's trick of calculating div sizes using 'calc'. These are what I consider to be the important points:

1) By using 'calc' with viewport-relative units, we can calculate how high the image must be if it is to be as wide as the viewport, and we can then make it have that height. By using the same calculation elsewhere, we can force other divs to have the same height. (One disadvantage of this is that it makes maintenance harder, because we have to update all the calculations whenever we change to an image with a different aspect ratio.)

2) Using 'rgba' rather than 'opacity' for the translucent background removes the problem about children inheriting their parent's opacity. This reduces the number of elements needed.

3) The way Ryan positioned his elements eliminated the need for z-indices, relying instead on CSS's rules for stacking order. (It could be argued that this is a disadvantage for maintenance, because the stacking order is no longer explicit.)

4) A bit of care was needed with vertical-align:top and with the implicit spacing that HTML inserts between display:inline-block elements.

Here's the code-snippet copy of http://www.j-paine.org/css_demos/test37.html :

```css
/* 
See  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174608/make-a-div-which-overlays-an-autoresizable-image-and-is-as-high-as-the-image-but
*/


.inner-div
  { width: 75%;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
  }
/*
This is my usual inner-div red bar.
*/


#image-holder-div
  { margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
/*
This is a div which imitates how Ryan
styled his body element. The image is 
positioned absolute within it.
*/


.image
  { position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vw / (700 /578));  
  }
/*
This positions the image absolute 
within the above div, and makes its
width scale with the browser width.
Unlike in test32, the scaling is done
with a 'calc', and should therefore
precisely match the height of .panel .
*/


#image-holder-div
  { width: 100%;
  }
/*
This is Ryan's wrapper for the panels.
*/


#panel-holder
  { position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 700px; 
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
/*
This is positioned relative within
wrapper, and was also Ryan's. It mimics 
the width and horizontal position of inner-div.
*/


.panel
  { display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 24%;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0.2 );
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: calc(100vw / (700 / 578));  
  }
/*
This is mainly Ryan's styling. He added
the display:inline-block and the use of
rgba for colour and opacity. The calc is
mine, imitating Gust van de Wal's answer
to my posting.
*/
```

```html
<center><h1>Test 37</h1></center>

<div class=inner-div style="margin-bottom:30px;">
</div>

<div id=image-holder-div>

  <img src="http://www.j-paine.org/catalogue/archers_big.jpeg" 
  class=image>

  <div id="image-overlay-div">

    <div id="panel-holder">

      <div class="panel">
        <a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">READ</a>      
      </div><!--

   --><div class="panel">
        <a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">MORE</a>
      </div><!--

   --><div class="panel">
        <a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">CARTOONS</a>
      </div><!--

   --><div class="panel">
        <a href="http://www.jocelyns-cartoons.uk">HERE!</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class=inner-div style="margin-top:30px;">
</div>
```